# ArrayBlockingQueue - blocking drainTo() method

Tags: java, concurrency

This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831834/blockingqueue-blocked-drainto-methods).

Is this a reasonable implementation for a blocking version of method `ArrayBlockingQueue.drainTo(Collection)`?

```
/**
 * This blocking method blends {@link #take()} with {@link #drainTo(Collection)}.
 * <br>
 * Chiefly, {@code take()} blocks and {@code drainTo(Collection)} does not block.
 */
public int drainAtLeastOneTo(Collection<? super E> c)
throws InterruptedException {
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        while (count == 0) {
            notEmpty.await();
        }
        final int x = drainTo(c);
        return x;
    }
    finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

To clarify: This code comes from the Sun JDK source code of `ArrayBlockingQueue`.  I simply blended the source from `take()` with `drainTo(Collection)`.

I am considering adding it to a modified version of `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

Comment: What is `notEmpty`? How much of your code is a rewrite of `ArrayBlockingQueue`? Your `lock` lock is completely useless too, each time a thread calls the method they will get a new lock instance, so you have not implemented any locking at all..... your code does not work... though I suspect you did not know that when you posted it.

Comment: I realize that your `lock` is a shadow-name of the instance `lock`. That's a bad practice - using the same names in methods variables as instance variables... my first comment above is "wrong".

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is easily solved without having to delve in to the internals of `ArrayBlockingQueue`, and without needing a new `ReEntrantLock` either. SImply use the methods that are currently available, and combine them....

```
public int drainAtLeastOneTo(Collection<? super E> c) 
        throws InterruptedException {
    c.add(take());
    return 1 + drainTo(c);
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea.  I will consider it.  However, your solution requires the caller to obtain (and free) the lock twice.  Mine only requires it once.  Why do I care?  I have an situation where the producer is relatively much faster than the consumer.  Thus, the consumer is sometimes starved on `take()`.  My idea was to "take more" with this method.

Comment: @kevinarpe then maybe a different queue is the answer

Comment: @kevinarpe - about the double-kick at the `lock` can, yes, I lock it twice, but, for the record, you do too... just you nest yours instead. `drainTo` has an internal lock, and nesting lock blocks may not be free either. Will need a performance test to check if it has a significant impact.